# Can people set loss function of neural network by themselves instead of choosing cross entropy or mean square error?

Tags: neural-networks, reinforcement-learning, objective-functions

I found people used deep neural network to get optimal policy by solving a nonconvex optimization problem. Moreover, they didn't use any set of training data and claimed that it's the difference between their approach and the supervised learning. I wonder can people set loss function of neural network by themselves instead of choosing cross entropy or mean square error?

My experience in machine learning is very limited. I audited two machine learning courses offered by applied math department in my school. I read twenty or more papers on the application of machine learning. I began to use Keras very recently.

Comment: I think it'd be better if you ask these as separate questions with more context..

Comment: Hello. Please, follow the suggestion above. Edit this post to [**ask only one question**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/39224) and provide more context/background, i.e. what do you know about neural networks and/or machine/deep learning so far?

Comment: Thanks very much. I will ask them as separate questions with more context.

Comment: [This Towards Data Science post on deep learning to do quantile regression](https://towardsdatascience.com/deep-quantile-regression-c85481548b5a) gets into how to implement your own loss function.